# TV To Application Communication Protocol

Tags: windows, protocols, hdmi, device-compatibility

I wish to develop a windows application that can steam video media to a TV. **What protocol/interface allows two-way communication between a TV and a Computer?**

I'm aware that HDMI is one-way communication (from the source to the TV) so the computers application cannot query what the current volume or current source is which is not useful. Is there a protocol that allows 2 way communication?

Also using HDMI is it possible to:

- Change a TV's source? For example change to/from HDMI, AV1, AV2, etc.?
- Change a TV's volume?

Or is it only possible to use HDMI to transmit video/audio data?

Answer (score 0):

HDMI wont be able to control other aspects of tv like changing the vole or source. You can just stream via HDMI. If you wish to manage other things i would prefer you do it with chromecast or apple tv or roku. Chromecast is easy to start off.